# React-admin tinymce - how to get content?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, react-admin

I'm an experienced Javascript developer, but new to React, so I'm looking for a bit of help.

This sandbox demonstrates the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-banzai-i46eg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

If you edit one of the posts, (and dismiss the TinyMCE license alert), you'll see the original content and can edit it.

When you edit the text,the new content is passed to the handleEditorChange() function in posts.js, from the custom rich edit component. (Sometimes you to tab out of the rich text for this to happen, which I'm not worried about).

However, if you save the change, the original text is POSTed to the dataprovider (as per your developer tools network tab), which implies the form record is not being updated.

How do I get the form record set to the new value from the editor?

Any help is much appreciated!

Regards,
Andy

Comment: A similar wrapper component already exists: https://github.com/LoicMahieu/aor-tinymce-input

Comment: Thanks @MaxAlex. I actually got the in the end by using the rich text input (essentially Quill.js) that comes with react-admin, which is the framework I'm using for the app. I was trying to add image upload capability, and managed to get it working with UploadCare. Appreciate your help anyway.